# Cast a Null String into Integer

Tags: java, casting

Is there any way to cast a null to Integer. The null is actually a String, which i am passing in my service layer that accepts it as an Integer. So, whenever i try to cast a null String to Integer, it throws me an exception. But i have to cast the null into Integer.

Comment: are you using `Integer.parseInt()` or just casting?

Comment: Can you provide a simple example in code? `null` inhabits all types in Java so a "String" `null` should be cast to an "Integer" `null` without issue.

Comment: can you show us the code lines that you are using ?

Comment: you can't CAST null to int (you can to Integer) - but you can create a method that runs null check and returns an int

Comment: by the way, what did CAST do to you, that you want to abuse it so much ? ;)

Comment: **Checkout my one-line code answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/77739302/4621922

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You **cannot** cast from String to Integer. However, if you are trying to convert string into integer and if you have to provide an implementation for handling `null` Strings, take a look at this code snippet:

```
String str = "...";
// suppose str becomes null after some operation(s).
int number = 0;
try
{
    if(str != null)
      number = Integer.parseInt(str);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    number = 0;
}
```

Comment: Catching `Exception` isn't usually a great idea; better to catch  `NumberFormatException` and `NullPointerException` individually.

Comment: @CraigRinger you are right! i changed my code accordingly. thanks for useful comment :)

Answer (score 24):

If you're using **apache commons**, there is an helper method that does the trick:

> `NumberUtils.createInteger(myString)`

As said in the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#createInteger%28java.lang.String%29):

"convert a `String` to a `Integer`, handling hex and octal notations; returns `null` if the string is `null`; throws `NumberFormatException` if the value cannot be converted.

Comment: Did this work for you? I tried it on a null String and it threw a NullPointerException...

Comment: It worked for me. Are you sure your NumberUtils is from apache commons and not another library?

Comment: But you should be aware that the method is not calling `Integer#parseInt()/valueOf()` but `Integer#decode()` instead!

Answer (score 8):

```
String s= "";  
int i=0;
i=Integer.parseInt(s+0);
System.out.println(i);
```

Try this

Comment: This is brilliant!

Comment: this should be `int.Parse(0 + s);` not the other way around. It will work regardless when `s` is an empty string, but if `s` is say... 11 you'll get 110 with the current approach.

Answer (score 2):

What about this ?

```
private static void castTest() {
    System.out.println(getInteger(null));
    System.out.println(getInteger("003"));
    int a = getInteger("55");
    System.out.println(a);
}

private static Integer getInteger(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return new Integer(0);
    } else {
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below `code:application` will return `0` if the string is null else it will parse the string to `int` if string contains a number alone..

Code:

```
(str.equals("null")?0:Integer.parseInt(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you only have to handle nulls,

```
int i=0;
i=(str==null?i:Integer.parseInt(str));
System.out.println(i);
```

for non integer strings it will throw Numberformat exception