# pass int array between activities

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent

I am trying to pass an int array to the next activity using Intent.
Here is the code.
to send

```
Intent mIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),activityvogel.class);
mIntent.putExtra("stock",stock);
startActivity(mIntent);}
```

to get

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int stock [] = extras.getIntArray("stock");
```

but i always get numberformatexception
here is my logcat

> 15015-15015/com.example.pantelis.ptyxiakh E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.pantelis.ptyxiakh, PID: 15015
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pantelis.ptyxiakh/com.example.pantelis.ptyxiakh.activityvogel}:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
>               at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
>               at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
>               at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
>               at com.example.pantelis.ptyxiakh.NextActivity.onCreate(NextActivity.java:41)
>               at com.example.pantelis.ptyxiakh.activityvogel.onCreate(activityvogel.java:19)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)

i would be grateful if anyone could help

Comment: How is `stock` declared and initialized in the code from which you send it?

Comment: int stock[]=new int[a1]  for (int i = 0; i < Ap1; i++) {
                    try {
                        if (allEdsP.get(i).getText().toString() != null)
                            stock[i] = Integer.parseInt(allEdsP.get(i).getText().toString());
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e){
                        stock[i]=0;
                    }     a1 is a value declared in the previous activity. stock takes values from Editexts,that's why i use integer.parseint

Comment: could you place a null string & empty string checking just before you doing a parseInt just as sujjested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595968/cast-a-null-string-into-integer

Comment: I have place checking before parseint. If an edittext is null, the value is 0, else I do the parseint